# micro DVI on 1st generation macbook air

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, dvi

is there a tested way to connect the Micro-DVI port of the Apple Macbook Air 1,1 (Early 2008) to the HDMI input of an HD TV?

The only way I know of, is Micro-DVI -> DVI-D (Apple adapter) and then DVI-D -> HDMI (cable), with a separate audio cable: has anyone tested this? are there suggested cable versions or brands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DVI (DVI = Digital Visual Interface) does never carry sound, it's visual only. Buying a Mini Displayport to HDMI does not help you out either because it's not supported for your Macbook Air.

```
Here's the list of laptop models that support audio pass-through via MDP

MacBook Air 11" Model 3,1
MacBook Air 11" Model 4,1
MacBook Air 11" Model 5,1

MacBook Air 13" Model 3,2
MacBook Air 13" Model 4,2
MacBook Air 13" Model 5,2

MacBook 13" Model 7,1

MacBook Pro 13" Model 7,1
MacBook Pro 13" Model 8,1
MacBook Pro 13" Model 9,2

MacBook Pro 15" Model 6,2
MacBook Pro 15" Model 8,2
MacBook Pro 15" Model 9,1
MacBook Pro 15" Model 10,1

MacBook Pro 17" Model 6,1
MacBook Pro 17" Model 8,3

and any version later
```

You can use the Apple MiniDisplayPort to DVI adapter with a cable like this: [image]
and a separate jack audio cable.

Comment: OK, so (forgetting about audio) the only way to connect it to an (HD TV) HDMI input is via a cable DVI-D to HDMI, right? are there any drawbacks or other things to pay attention to?

Comment: With an Apple TV you can stream your data to a TV including music. If you plug it in the DVI in the TV you can use a double Jack sound plug to add sound.
You can also use VGA if you'd like but that one is kinda.. old..

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of micro DVI port -> DVI-D (Apple adapter) DVI-D -> HDMI (cable) with a separate audio cable, would it work?

Comment: Yes, check my edit

Comment: I don't understand: my laptop has a microDVI, not a minidisplayport, how is that edit supposed to work?

Comment: also, a more elegant solution like an adapter from microDVI to HDMI directly isn't available?

Comment: also, using 2 adapters does it risk to 'corrupt' the signal? is there any particular cable brand which someone has experience works fine?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13249/robuuustnl

Answer (score 2):

[DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) does not pass through sound, just video. You will need to use a separate cable for the sound.